# Maven error: Package matlabcontrol does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I've added the following .jars as external jars to Libraries.

C:\Users\user\Downloads\common-lang3.jar\common-lang3.jar
C:\Users\user\Downloads\matlabcontrol\matlabcontrol-4.1.0.jar

However, during clean install of a Maven build in Eclipse, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project com.webapp: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:

[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/workspace/GetTimeDistance/src/com/MatLabClass.java:[4,21] package matlabcontrol does not exist

[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/workspace/GetTimeDistance/src/com/MatLabClass.java:[7,40] package org.apache.commons.lang3.builder does not exist
```

The source of the jars in the library are pointing to the correct jars.
I am able to use the code in the jars in my own code.

When hoovering over the import, I get the following Note:

```
Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.
```

Any idea's? I already updated the Maven project several times.

**EDIT:**
I've added:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.matlabcontrol</groupId>
        <artifactId>matlabcontrol</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>`
```

To the .pom file. This gives the following warning:
 [WARNING] The POM for org.matlabcontrol:matlabcontrol:jar:4.1.0 is missing, no dependency information available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run from maven, all the dependent jars will be referenced from maven repository only. 
It wont take any external libraries or jars. You define maven dependencies of the required jars in your pom.xml. If you want the local jars to be copied into your maven repository, below  is the cmd
 `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=your_local_path_of_jar -DgroupId=your_groupID -DartifactId=your_artifcat_id -Dversion=your_version -Dpackaging=jar`

Comment: Thank you. Is there an option in Eclipse with the Maven plugin to do this?

Comment: When I try the mvn install in cmd,:

[INFO] This project has been banned from the build due to previous failures.

Comment: Got it! After adding the matlabcontrol.jar to the workspace dir & running: mvn install:install-file -Dfile=matlabcontrol-4.1.0.jar -DgroupId=org.matlabcontrol -DartifactId=matlabcontrol -Dversion=4.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar, it compiled. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you work with eclispe and added the external jars to the "Build path" of your Project properties? The "Build path" is used by the eclipse IDE to resolve classes within the workspace, and has no influence on which libraries are used when performing a maven build. Most likely, you missed to define commons-lang and matlabcontrol as dependencies in your pom.xml file...

Comment: As shown in the edit, i've added the dependencies. The matlabcontrol dependacy creates a missing artifact.